# Можно ли "донестись НА"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, предлоги, глаголы

Например, "мы быстро донеслись на верхнюю точку хребта".

Объясню нюансы. "Вознеслись" написать нельзя, так как "воз" предполагает движение только вверх, а в контексте подразумевается общая проделанная дорога и до объекта, и на его вершину. "Донеслись **до**" звучит лучше, чем "донеслись **на**", но не отражает мысль, так как подходит для описания движения по прямой от и **до**, а до объекта нужно ещё проделать дополнительный путь вверх. Или я мудрю?

Можно, конечно, обойти неудобство, используя "добрались до", сомнения бы отпали. Но в моём контексте нужен акцент на скорости, так что использование "неслись" принципиально.
В итоге спрашиваю: можно ли *донестись **на***, а если нет, то какие есть тесные по смыслу варианты?

Отдельно подчёркиваю: "неслись" не заменяется на ехали/летели/скакали, исходя из того, что в контексте предполагается смена способа передвижения, а предложение сообщает общую информацию.

Comment: А "перенестись на", "добраться до" или "перебраться на" никак нельзя? "Донестись" с любыми предлогами странно воспринимается.

Comment: @Alex_ander Перенестись — это уже про телепортацию. Добраться/перебраться — теряет впечатление скорости. На счёт донестись: ну, звук же способен доноситься на большие расстояния и до чьего-то слуха. Например, звук может донестись на тот берег. Почему люди не могут донестись на что-то.

Comment: В значении "довершить путь" не воспринимается и вообще по отношению к одушевлённым существам (за звуком закрепилось).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А мне кажется, что вполне возможно донестись НА что-то...

Вот у [**Ушакова**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/793214/%D0%94%D0%9E%D0%9D%D0%95%D0%A1%D0%A2%D0%98%D0%A1%D0%AC):
**донестись**
2. Очень быстро доехать, добежать (*разг.*). **В полчаса донесся до дому.**

Вот у  [**К. Д. Бальмонта**](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%88_(%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82)):

*Луна была сокрыта в дымных тучах,

Возросших как леса и города.

Все ждали тайн и ласк блаженно жгучих.*

***Мы донеслись по воздуху туда,

На кладбище,*** к уюту усыплённых,
Где люди днём лишь бродят иногда.

Если в полчаса можно донестись до дому, что же мешает за эти же полчаса (или меньшее-большее время) донестись **на** гору?
Только глагол "донестись" **уже** предполагает **особую быстроту действия**,  поэтому слово "быстро" здесь, как мне думается, излишне.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю вариант "домчались". В нем и скорость, и отсутствие указания на способ передвижения. Обратите внимание: домчались до чего-то, а не на что-то.

[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C) дает разговорное значение глогола *донестись*:

> ДОНЕСТИСЬ.....Разг. Быстро доехать, добежать; домчаться.

Но, во-первых, донестись *до* а не *на*, а во-вторых — слишком уж просторечно в данном случае.